# How to access tailwind theme values in source code with typescript

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, google-search

I want to access my theme config in my source code using typescript.
The following works, because of the `any`, but I want to use Typescript properly. When I remove the `as any` I always and up with `this property doesn't exist` or similar typescript errors.

```
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from '../../../../tailwind.config';

const {theme: {screens}} = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig) as any;
console.log(screens.md)
```

removing 'as any' leads to error:

```
Property 'screens' does not exist on type 'UnwrapResolvables<{ extend: { colors: { "bento-main": string; "bento-bg": string; "bento-sub": string; "bento-sub-alt": string; "bento-text": string; }; content: { gear: string; }; inset: { 'shadow-spread': string; }; gap: { 'y-mansonry': string; 'x-mansonry': string; }; }; }>'.ts(2339
```

I guess the following type in tailwindcss/resolveConfig.d.ts leads to Typescript expecting a `theme.extend`, which doesn't exist at runtime. So typescript doesn't complain when I access my `theme.extend.` values, but that in turn fails at runtime.

```
type ResolvedConfig<T extends Config> = Omit<T, 'theme'> & {
  theme: UnwrapResolvables<T['theme']>
}
```

I wonder why I'm not able to find someone who did this before, since tailwind is so popular and accessing theme values should be a very common occurence. Are you able to construct a google search that finds source code that did this? And/Or do you now how to use the tailwind's typescript types properly?

Comment: Does this help you? https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/8920

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/8920#issuecomment-1191783489) inside tailwind-resolve-config.d.ts in your types/typings directory

```
declare module 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig' {
    import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';

    declare function resolveConfig(config: Config): Config;
    export = resolveConfig;
}
```